# Django - DisallowedHost at /

Tags: python, django, linux, webservice, ubuntu

Acabo de hacer "despliegue" de un proyecto django. **La web no se ve.** Está desplegado en un servidor Ubuntu con nginx, gunicorn y supervisor, pero me sale lo siguiente al ver la web en internet.

¿qué sucede?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Tiene algo que ver lo siguiente del archivo setting?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias.

Comment: [Esto responde a tu pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3041/150301)

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar colocar la IP del host. `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['104.248.95.173']`. Recuerda colocar `DEBUG=False` en producción.